# VirtualServer not routing to paths

Tags: nginx-ingress

I have a rke kubernetes one node cluster in my laptop virtual box,
configured metallb LB and configured nginx VirtualServer with the following routes.

Routes:
1st route : https://cart.example.com/desktops
2st route : https://cart.example.com/laptops

if we try https://cart.example.com/servers # return route message
it display a return message in the browser.

### My issue no routes works for me except return,

### What is verified

```
I can able to curl laptop-POD-IP and desktop-POD-IP.
In the ingressController POD i can see the VirtualServer object created.

curl -Ik https://cart.example.com/laptops
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found  ## 404 error
Server: nginx/1.23.3
Date: Fri, 14 Apr 2023 09:37:04 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Connection: keep-alive


curl -Ik https://cart.example.com/desktops
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found   # 404 error
Server: nginx/1.23.3
Date: Fri, 14 Apr 2023 09:37:12 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 153
Connection: keep-alive

# It worked because, its has a return Response...
curl -Ik https://cart.example.com/servers
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.23.3
Date: Fri, 14 Apr 2023 09:37:18 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 55
Connection: keep-alive
```

### virtualserver.yaml

```
apiVersion: k8s.nginx.org/v1
kind: VirtualServer
metadata:
  name: cart-vs
spec:
  host: cart.example.com
  tls:
    secret: cart-secret
    redirect:
      enable: true   
      code: 301
  upstreams:
  - name: desktops
    service: desktops-svc
    port: 80
    lb-method: round_robin
  - name: laptops
    service: laptops-svc
    port: 80
    lb-method: round_robin
  routes:
  - path: /
    action:
      redirect:
        url: https://cart.example.com/laptops
        code: 302
  - path: /desktops
    action:
      pass: desktops
  - path: /laptops
    action:
      pass: laptops
  - path: /servers
    action:
      return:
        code: 200
        type: text/html
        body: "Welcome to NGINX Ingress Controller !!"
```

### Desktop.yaml

```
cat desktops-dep-srv.yml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: desktops
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: desktops
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: desktops
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: desktops
        #image: httpd:latest
        image: nginx:1.19.6
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: desktops-svc
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  clusterIP: None
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 80
    protocol: TCP
    name: http
  selector:
    app: desktops
```

### laptops.yaml

```
cat laptops-dep-srv.yml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: laptops
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: laptops
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: laptops
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: laptops
        image: httpd-v1:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: laptops-svc
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  clusterIP: None
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 80
    protocol: TCP
    name: http
  selector:
    app: laptops
```